# Why table column width is changed?

Tags: css

```
<div id="reportContent">
    <table id='insideTable5' border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Sensor Name</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Senosr No</th>
            <th colspan="9">Temperature</th>
            <th colspan="9">Humidity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Min</td>
            <td>Max</td>
            <td>Mean</td>
            <td>Spread</td>
            <td>Count</td>
            <td>LowRange</td>
            <td>&#60;Low</td>
            <td>HighRange</td>
            <td> High</td>
            <td>Min</td>
            <td>Max</td>
            <td>Mean</td>
            <td>Spread</td>
            <td>Count</td>
            <td>LowRange</td>
            <td>&#60;Low</td>
            <td>HighRange</td>
            <td> High</td>
        </tr>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var i=0;
            for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
            {
                document.write('<tr class="even"><td>sensor1</td><td>0410-00370</td><td>19.5</td><td>24.0</td><td>21.6</td><td>4.5</td><td>48</td><td>Not Set</td><td>0</td><td>Not Set</td><td>0</td><td>19.5</td><td>24.0</td><td>21.6</td><td>4.5</td><td>48</td><td>Not Set</td><td>0</td><td>Not Set</td><td>0</td></tr>');
            }
        </script>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <table id='insideTable5' border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Sensor Name</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Senosr No</th>
            <th colspan="9">Temperature</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Min</td>
            <td>Max</td>
            <td>Mean</td>
            <td>Spread</td>
            <td>Count</td>
            <td>LowRange</td>
            <td>&#60;Low</td>
            <td>HighRange</td>
            <td> High</td>
        </tr>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var i=0;
            for (i=0;i<=3;i++)
            {
                document.write('<tr class="even"><td>sensor1</td><td>0410-00370</td><td>19.5</td><td>24.0</td><td>21.6</td><td>4.5</td><td>48</td><td>Not Set</td><td>0</td><td>Not Set</td><td>0</td></tr>');
            }
        </script>
    </table>
</div>
```

Below is the output of the above code,
[image]

As seen from the image, the columns of "Sensor Name" have got the equal width for both tables.But once adding the following css, two tables have the different width for the "Sensor Name" column. My question is how to make "Sensor Name" columns having the same width after adding the following css.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #reportContent{
        width: 714px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: add css class to sensor column

Comment: I cant see a difference... http://jsfiddle.net/FU8fV/

Answer (score 2):

add css class to sensor column

```
<th rowspan="2" class="sensorName">Sensor Name</th>
<td>sensor1</td><td class="sensorName">
```

---

```
.sensorName{
width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,@JapanPro, after add ur code, two tables still show the different width for the "Sensor Name" column.

Comment: @emily-bcot, it should work please post jsfiddle, so i can correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css:

```
table th:nth-child(1), table th:nth-child(2), 
table td:nth-child(1), table td:nth-child(2)
{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/g7qLP/1/)